# Removing minutes from Timestamp

Tags: scala

Im using

```
val unix_startTime = startTime.getTime - (((startTime.getTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60) * 60000)
```

to round of Timestamp example

> 2018-01-08 19:16:21     To  2018-01-08 19:00:21
>
> 2018-01-08 19:56:21    To  2018-01-08 19:00:21

Is there any built in function to achieve this in crisp?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
val df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:ss")
df.format(new Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`java.time`**

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format._
val startTime = "2018-01-08 19:16:21"
val formatterFrom = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val formatterTo = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:ss")
val unix_startTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startTime, formatterFrom).format(formatterTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, use `java.time` API in which classes are immutable and thread-safe.  To zero out minutes, you can use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) method `plusMinutes`, as in the following example:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val date = "2018-01-08 19:16:21"

val localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(
  date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
)
// localDate: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2018-01-08T19:16:21

localDate.plusMinutes(-localDate.getMinute)
// res1: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2018-01-08T19:00:21
```